# PHP fscanf vs fgets

Tags: php, fgets, scanf

I am able to read an entire string in a line using `fgets()` but `fscanf()` is not doing so.

According to PHP manual

> fscanf — Parses input from a file according to a format
>
> The function `fscanf()` is similar to `sscanf()`, but it takes its input from a file associated with handle and interprets the input according to the specified format, which is described in the documentation for `sprintf()`.
>
> fgets — Gets line from file pointer
>
> Gets a line from file pointer.

Since `fscanf()` supports formats as mentioned above I can use `%s` to read an entire line but instead it reads only one word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PHP documentation of `fscanf()` and `sscanf()` is not complete. The formats are similar to the ones used by `printf()`, but they're not exactly the same. When you're printing, `%s` will print any string, but when you're scanning it just reads a word. To get more complete information, you need to read the documentation of the `C` `fscanf()` function. Some of this information is also in the comments section of the documentation web page.

To read a whole line with `fscanf()`, use `"%[^\\n]"`. In `fscanf()`, `$[^characters]` means to match any sequence of characters that isn't in the set between the brackes (it's similar to `[^characters]*` in a regular expression). So this matches any sequence of characters other than newline. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php#56076

Comment: Thanks that did the trick but I tried **%[^ \ ]** and it still works so what is the need for **\n**.

Comment: The brackets are supposed to contain at least one character to exclude. Maybe it works in PHP because it automatically stops at the end of the line even if you don't say so explicitly.

Comment: According to PHP Manual                                                                        Each call to fscanf() reads one line from the file.